# Why do we need Atomic* classes if wrapper classes are already immutable?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I recently encountered atomic classes from [java.util.concurrent.atomic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) package. As far as I know, immutable classes are by default thread safe by nature, so we do not need to synchronize them. Later I came to know that wrapper classes like Integer, Boolean, Character, etc are immutable by nature, so why do we need Atomic* classes like AtomicInteger or AtomicLong. Also, please explain what is [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html).

Comment: Atomic classes are **mutable**.

Comment: Because ... maybe you want an atomic class that isn't immutable?

Comment: @Eran I agree, but wrapper classes will work in multithreaded environment, then why atomic class is required. Is David's reason the main reason they created them.

Comment: With immutable classes alone, all you can share is constants. I think it doesn't take a lot of imagination to realize that sometimes you need more than constants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The atomic classes are *mutable*, but have strong memory consistency guarantees with regard to modifications. So they serve a different purpose from the immutable wrapper classes.

The real advantage of the `Atomic*` classes is that they expose an atomic [compare-and-swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) method, which can be very useful for implementing [lock-free algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm).

Like many intermediate to advanced concurrency tools, if you can't imagine why you would need such a thing then you probably shouldn't try to use them. If you stick to immutability or explicit locking everywhere then you probably won't need atomics.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940670/how-atomicity-is-achieved-in-the-classes-defined-in-java-util-concurrent-atomic) is a nice question about what the `compareAndSet` principle.

From documentation:

- The specifications of these methods enable implementations to employ efficient machine-level atomic instructions that are available on contemporary processors.

Reading about [atomic / volatile / synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9749864/5091346) will help you to maintain the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever thought when I have an `Integer(1)`,how can I change it to `Integer(2)`,Integer is immutable.so I need create new one and set it value,but the process is not atomic.

Comment: atomic!=immutable

Answer (score 0):

Concept of atomicity comes when something is mutable.
We want the operation of modifying a field/variable (could be many steps, read -> update -> write) as atomic operation. So that in multithreaded scenario, there should not be any data corruption.
[java.util.concurrent.atomic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) package does it for us.
Wrapper classes are immutable, we can't modify it, need to create a new instance.